# unordered_map of shared_ptrs breaks C++ program

Tags: c++, debugging, boost, c++11

I use an `unordered_map` in my current C++ project and have the following problem:

When I insert a pair of objects into the `unordered_map`, the programm breaks and Windows shows me it's "[...].exe has stopped working", without giving me any information on the console (cmd). Some example code:

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>

#include <network/server/NetPlayer.h>
#include <gamemodel/Player.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    NetGame game;
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    NetPlayerPtr net(new NetPlayer(io_service, game));
    PlayerPtr player(new Player);

    std::unordered_map<PlayerPtr, NetPlayerPtr> player_map;

    // Here it breaks:
    player_map[player] = net;

    return 0;
}
```

## What I already tried:

I tried wrapping the line with a try-catch, but without success.

## Details about the code:

NetPlayerPtr and PlayerPtr are `boost::shared_ptr` objects, the former contains some `boost::asio` objects like `io_service` and `socket`, the latter contains several custom objects.

I'm compiling with MinGW gcc with C++11 enabled on a 64bit Windows.

If more details are needed, please ask.

Comment: No, I have no expirience with debuggers like GDB (if you're talking about that).

Comment: @m--s now is your chance!

Comment: Seems true. Any good ressources on this? :D (Just kidding, gonna google it myself)

Comment: Can we see the specialization of `std::hash` for `PlayerPtr`? Also, why are you using a `boost::shared_ptr` instead of a `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: @FredOverflow The hash for `PlayerPtr` is defined like [this](https://gist.github.com/85e0b4c60471411a91c9).
I use `boost::shared_ptr` because when I began working on this project, I had some problems enabling C++11 on MinGW GCC and now it'd take a bit to switch to `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Erm... you have an infinite recursion in your `hash<PlayerPtr>` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, let's look at the code you linked to:

```
namespace std
{
    template<>
    class hash<Player>
    {
    public:
        size_t operator()(const Player &p) const
        {
            // Hash using boost::uuids::uuid of Player
            boost::hash<boost::uuids::uuid> hasher;
            return hasher(p.id);
        }
    };

    template<>
    class hash<PlayerPtr>
    {
    public:
        size_t operator()(const PlayerPtr &p) const
        {
            return hash<PlayerPtr>()(p);   // infinite recursion
        }
    };
}
```

You have an inifinite recursion in your `hash<PlayerPtr>::operator()`. What you probably want is:

```
return hash<Player>()(*p);
```

or:

```
return hash<Player*>()(p->get());
```

depending on whether you want to identify the player by its internal id or its address.

Comment: Hmm... I need to supply `hash` for a variable. Oh well, let's just `std::hash` it! Genius! :)